# How Do I Add an Embedded Resource to a "Class Library (Package)" Project in VS 2015 RC?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

There is a new project template in the Visual Studio 2015 release candidate called "Class Library (Package)." It's in the Visual C#/Web category. In the information panel of the project type, it says "PREVIEW - A project template for creating a class library as a NuGet package that can target any platform."

I'm doing something similar that I did in a normal Class Library project and involves an embedded resource. Normally, there's an option in the Properties dialog that allows you to specify a "Build Action." You can then select "Embedded Resource." That option does not appear in the Properties dialog for a file in a "Class Library (Project)" project.

Does anybody know how to add an embedded resource to a "Class Library (Package)" project in VS 2015 RC? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the default magic `/compiler/resources` that you can use to drop files in and they will be embedded automatically.  I have an example @ https://github.com/Blacklite/Features/tree/master/src/Blacklite.Framework.Features.Http ( Note as of this post, it was not updated to beta4, but the functionality hasn't changed to my knowledge )

Also as per the schema, you can point at a specific folder using the "resources" key in your `project.json`.
See: http://json.schemastore.org/project

Comment: I stumbled across this post a few moments ago.  I *think* I have the resource (.resx file) embedded in my assembly.  How do I access it?

Comment: .resx files are another story, they are not automatically compiled in the same way they are with the MSBuild based tasks.  If you're looking to just read the xml of .resx, then you just need to read the file out of the assembly using the same methods you would read any embedded resource from an assembly.

Comment: Coming from C and I just can't believe what an utter mess all this is lmao.