# How to use a resource file in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm creating integration tests **(web class library project)** for my ASP5 MVC6 application. I want to add a resource file with raw SQL to the test project for DB preparation.

I wanted to use good old resources (.resx). But I it's not available in `add new item` project's menu.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30225815/672018) answer pointing to a [github repo](https://github.com/Blacklite/Features/blob/master/src/Blacklite.Framework.Features.Http/Extensions/FeatureOptions.cs). I guess this is where he reads the file:

```
using (var stream = FileProvider.GetFileInfo("compiler/resources/layout.html").CreateReadStream())
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    return streamReader.ReadToEnd().Replace("~", $"{basePath}/compiler/resources");
                }
```

I tried using `System.IO.File.ReadAllText("compiler/resources/my.sql")` in my **test helper** project in TestHelper class.

When I used the TestHelper class in my actual test project it was looking for the the file in test project directory.

`TestProject/compiler/resources/my.sql` insetad of `TestHelperProject/compiler/resources/my.sql`

I can figure out a couple of workarounds. However I'd like to do it the right way. Preferably like I would do in with a resx file:

```
string sql = Resources.MySql;
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

Project type
[image]

Available items
[image]

Comment: What project template are you using, exactly? I don't see "Web Class Library Project" in the New ASP.NET Project template selector.

Comment: FWIW, the "Resources File" (with a `.resx` extension) **does** appear in the Add New Item dialog in ASP.NET Projects in Visual Studio 2015, under the "Visual C# > General" category.

Comment: @Dai See the edit please. BTW if I create a normal Class Library project and try to add a reference to my ASP5 project I get an error "A reference to 'MyAsp5Project' could not be added'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little more complicated because there's no tooling support but it is doable:

1. Create a `resx` file or copy it from somewhere else like a classic C# project
2. If you can use `sake` as the build system, then you can use the same target that we, the ASP.NET team use: https://github.com/aspnet/Universe/blob/dev/build/_k-generate-resx.shade otherwise, you need to implement something similar in your own build scripts
3. Place the resources either `compiler/resources`. If you place them under any other folder then include them in the project json (like [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/project.json#L18))
4. Build using sake then build using dnx. Your resource should be available as a strong type object

Comment: Well.. this is kind of tedious. Are there plans to restore the tooling?

Comment: Hi Victor! what about using IHtmlLocalizer for localization?

Comment: So it looks like Visual Studio Update 1 added tooling support for this? It doesn't look like it's complete just yet, as other classes in the same project don't seem to pick up any new resources right away and you can't change the access modifier. In those regards, it's a step backwards, but at least it seems to be there again.

Comment: Links are dead.